# How to hide "You are now logged out" message on Wordpress login form?

Tags: logout

**Expectation:**
I want to hide the login message that shows up on the Wordpress login form after a user has logged out. Added screenshot of the message that I am trying to hide.

https://i.imgur.com/vJm56sI

Wordpress Version 5.4.2

Wordpres theme: Oceanwp 1.8.9

I have used the below mentioned code in the functions.php file of my theme.

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'my_logout_message' );

function my_logout_message( $errors ){

    if ( isset( $errors->errors['loggedout'] ) ){
        return null;
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

**Error Recieved:**

I have provided the screen shot of the error that I have recieved.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzA3Y.png

Also, the login form isn't visible after user logout.

Comment: What's the reason behind this? Can you provide some context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your error is that the filter receives and is expected to return a `WP_Error` object, `null` is not an error object.

We can confirm this via the docs, and enforce it via type hinting:

```php
function my_logout_message( \WP_Error $error ) : \WP_Error {
```

Additionally, if your code had worked, all errors would be eliminated, not just the logout message. There would be no way to tell a user their password was incorrect, that a password reset email or a confirmation email was on its way, etc

With this in mind, the `WP_Error` say there is a `remove` method, so we can remove the loggedout error if it's present:

```php
$error->remove( 'loggedout' );
```

I do not recommend this though